# Python location on osx in recovery mode

Tags: python, macos, osx-mavericks

Where can I find the python binary once osx is booted in recovery mode? 
I cannot locate it in any bin directory: /usr/bin, /bin, /sbin.
It's pretty curious since python is shipped with osx by default.
I need to run a python script in recovery mode and I cannot use cx_Freeze since it compiles the binaries with python3 interpreter instead of python2.6 (which I need)

Answer (score 1):

It may not be there at all. The OS X recovery mode uses a separate partition on your HDD, i.e. the files you see there are most probably the files that are in the /usr/bin of that partition, not the files which are in the equivalent folder of your main hard disk.

The main hard disk is available at:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD
```

Unfortunately all paths are desperately wrong, so the python cannot be called directly from there (e.g. /Volumes/Macintosh HD/usr/bin/python).

I do not know if this could be mounted to the root without breaking something badly. Possibly not.

However, it might just be possible to install python into the recovery terminal. But do you need only python interpreter or also a number of external modules? And could you use the single-user mode instead of the recovery mode? I cannot think of too many things you can do in recovery mode but not in the single-user mode apart from some operations which require the main HDD to be unmounted. (In which case you certainly cannot use the python on it.)

Comment: Thanks for answering me Drv: I need to run a python script with a live os and disconnected from the internet. I thought the recovery mode could be a nice shot, but no python seems to be available then. Yes, I need some external modules within my script. How can I install the python interpreter on the recovery shell? Maybe my best alternative is finding a bash script to replace the python one.

Comment: Installing python into the recovery mode is probably possible and probably difficult. So, if you can live with a bash script, you are better off. However, you should have a look at the single user mode, because it is usually better suited for all sorts of maintenance operations.